# SQL query - rows to seperate columns when other columns in the table have certain value

Tags: oracle, pivot

I am stuck at a particular task within an OracleDB. I am using SQLDeveloper to write the sql query and I need to convert rows to columns in respect of other columns data.

When in the column "SPRID" the value is "DE" and the "ARTTXTNUMMER" is "1" I need to put the value of "ARTTXTTXT" in the column "TXT1-DE".
When in the column "SPRID" the value is "IT" and the "ARTTXTNUMMER" is "1" I need to put the value of "ARTTXTTXT" in the column "TXT1-IT" of the same row as the value of "TXT1-DE".
When in the column "SPRID" the value is "DE" and the "ARTTXTNUMMER" is "2" I need to put the value of "ARTTXTTXT" in the column "TXT2-DE".
When in the column "SPRID" the value is "IT" and the "ARTTXTNUMMER" is "2" I need to put the value of "ARTTXTTXT" in the column "TXT2-IT".

I even did a LEFT JOIN with 2 tables.

My query looks like this:

```html
SELECT
    artikel.artid,
    artikel.artkode,
    artikel.artbarcode,
    artikeltexte.arttxtnummer,
    artikeltexte.sprid,
    artikeltexte.arttxttext,
    artikel.herstellid
FROM
    artikel
    LEFT JOIN artikeltexte ON artikel.artid = artikeltexte.artid
```

The output is this:

```
ARTID   ARTKODE ARTBARCODE  ARTTXTNUMMER    SPRID   ARTTXTTEXT  HERSTELLID
074L    260631 802863300108 1   DE  txt074L-1-DE    4568794H
074L    260631 802863300108 1   IT  txt074L-1-IT    4568794H
074L    260631 802863300108 2   DE  txt074L-2-DE    4568794H
074L    260631 802863300108 2   IT  txt074L-2-IT    4568794H
071A    784520 80781200896  1   DE  txt071A-1-DE    4577882H
071A    784520 80781200896  1   IT  txt071A-1-IT    4577882H
073W    898000 87846213567  1   DE  txt073W-1-DE    4505020H
073W    898000 87846213567  1   IT  txt073W-1-IT    4505020H
073W    898000 87846213567  2   DE  txt073W-2-DE    4505020H
073W    898000 87846213567  2   IT  txt073W-2-IT    4505020H
```

As you can see there are multiple rows for each article. I need to have 1 row per article with information in columns like this:

```
    ARTID   ARTKODE ARTBARCODE  ARTTXTTEXT  HERSTELLID  TXT1-DE TXT1-IT TXT2-DE TXT2-IT
074L    260631  802863300108    txt074L-1-DE    4568794H    txt074L-1-DE    txt074L-1-IT    txt074L-2-DE    txt074L-2-IT
071A    784520  80781200896 txt071A-1-DE    4577882H    txt071A-1-DE    txt071A-1-IT        
073W    898000  87846213567 txt073W-2-IT    4505020H    txt073W-1-DE    txt073W-1-IT    txt073W-2-DE    txt073W-2-IT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use  CASE when for a selective filter and a (fake)  aggregation 
 (min in this sample )  function for compact the rows

```
  SELECT
      artikel.artid,
      artikel.artkode,
      artikel.artbarcode,
      artikeltexte.arttxtnummer,
      artikeltexte.arttxttext,
      artikel.herstellid,
      min(case when SPRID = 'DE' and ARTTXTNUMMER = 1 THEN ARTTXTTXT else null END ) TXT1_DE, 
      min(case when SPRID = 'IT' and ARTTXTNUMMER = 1 THEN ARTTXTTXT else null END ) TXT1_IT,  
      min(case when SPRID = 'DE' and ARTTXTNUMMER = 2 THEN ARTTXTTXT else null END ) TXT2_DE, 
      min(case when SPRID = 'IT' and ARTTXTNUMMER = 2 THEN ARTTXTTXT else null END ) TXT2_IT  
  FROM
      artikel
      LEFT JOIN artikeltexte ON artikel.artid = artikeltexte.artid
  GROUP BY artikel.artid,
      artikel.artkode,
      artikel.artbarcode,
      artikeltexte.arttxtnummer,
      artikeltexte.arttxttext,
      artikel.herstellid
```

if you need  a row for each artikle  you should remove (or group_concat) the value that don't let a proper group by eg:

```
    SELECT
      artikel.artid,
      artikel.artkode,
      artikel.artbarcode,
      artikel.herstellid,
      min(case when SPRID = 'DE' and ARTTXTNUMMER = 1 THEN ARTTXTTXT else null END ) TXT1_DE, 
      min(case when SPRID = 'IT' and ARTTXTNUMMER = 1 THEN ARTTXTTXT else null END ) TXT1_IT,  
      min(case when SPRID = 'DE' and ARTTXTNUMMER = 2 THEN ARTTXTTXT else null END ) TXT2_DE, 
      min(case when SPRID = 'IT' and ARTTXTNUMMER = 2 THEN ARTTXTTXT else null END ) TXT2_IT  
  FROM
      artikel
      LEFT JOIN artikeltexte ON artikel.artid = artikeltexte.artid
  GROUP BY artikel.artid,
      artikel.artkode,
      artikel.artbarcode,
      artikel.herstellid
```

Comment: Hi there. Thank you for your rapid answer. I tried to run this code but it says on line 8 (where the min case begins) is an error.

00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: show me the exact error message please .. there was a wrong table name after the group by and i have already update the answer  for this

Comment: I think i have found .... the use of name  as TXT.-DE is not allowed (the use of sign in column or alias name)  .. so i have changed with TXT_DE .. answer  updated  .

Comment: ok now it works. But the result is not as expected. I still get out 4 rows for the same article. There should be only 1 row per article with the diffrent columns filled.

Comment: Thank you very much! I see... I have to remove always the columns in the select statement, if they cause multiple rows. Thanks!